# remarks in an alter table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was supposed to do a remarks (in order to add a comment) during my table creation but I forgot.

How can I do it in an alter?

I use postgres

Comment: `comment on table x is 'blah'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html

> `COMMENT` stores a comment about a database object.
>
> Only one comment string is stored for each object, so to modify a
>   comment, issue a new COMMENT command for the same object. To remove a
>   comment, write NULL in place of the text string.
>
> **Examples**
>
> Attach a comment to the table mytable:
>
> ```
> COMMENT ON TABLE mytable IS 'This is my table.';
> ```